# etherscan or ethplorer doesn't see test transaction

Tags: ethereum

I want to get address transaction list and as I can see that is possible only if dancing with a tambourine. So I decided to use some third party service(which I think shame for ethereum developers but we have that what we have). But those service can't see transactions or balance on the address even balance showing via command

```
 curl -X POST http://localhost:8545 -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBalance","params":"0xcd88f3430a2e01e61554e655719e0f92d3e1ba37", "pending"],"id":1}'


{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0xde0b6b3a7640000"}
```

(sent via goerli)

but when I perform request like

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xcd88f3430a2e01e61554e655719e0f92d3e1ba37&sort=asc&apikey=...
```

I get

```
message "No transactions found"
```

Or on

```
https://kovan-api.ethplorer.io/getAddressTransactions/0xcd88f3430a2e01e61554e655719e0f92d3e1ba37?apiKey=...

[]
```

Can you please explain to me what happen and how easily to extract transaction list for the address.

Comment: Usually the reason is that the sending account does not have enough balance to process the transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, need to use different domain for `goerli` transactions

https://api-goerli.etherscan.io/